# ¿Cómo realizo una única consulta para varios métodos de mi proyecto laravel?

Tags: laravel-8

la situación es la siguiente, tengo un controlador y dentro de este hay una consulta que se repite para varios métodos, por lo cual quisiera preguntar si hay forma de realizar una única consulta y en la variable que se guarde, poderla usar en estos métodos y no realizar la misma consulta para varios métodos, gracias

Esta es la consulta que se debe realizar

Comment: Darwin, donde defines la clase (controlador?, puedes definir un método `private` o `protected` que te haga esa consulta, y utilizarlo en el resto, ¿no? O si también quieres utilizarlo desde fuera, también `public`, pero eso ya depende de tus necesidades.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas un ejemplo para que quede más clara la pregunta e incluso que la respuesta sea más directa a tu problema